# rails 3: looking for simple solution to adding 3 tabs to a report view (need css to draw tabs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, tabs

I've seen various solutions for adding tabbed navigation to a rails 3 app, but what I need is much simpler (in theory)...

On one of my views, I have three short reports: the 'overview' section, 'detail 1' and 'detail 2'

Right now my view (HAML) displays them sequentially:

```
%h1 Sales Summary
(haml to display about 15 lines of summary data)

%h1 Sales by Region
(haml to display 15-20 lines about widget sales sorted one way)

%h1 Sales by Product
(haml to display 15-20 lines sorted a different way)
```

I'd like instead to have the three headings be in 3 reasonably attractive horizontal tabs, and simply hide/show the appropriate data based on which tab they click.

I would prefer a non-js approach (that works with browsers with javascript disabled), meaning I'm fine with re-drawing the page based on a url param such as "view=tab1"

I can see how to do it as a table, but I can't get that to look very 'tab like'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could comes in handy: http://unraveled.com/publications/css_tabs/

Still the no js constraint seems anachronistic so I encourage you to check jQuery's tabs: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

It's straight to include in your code and compatible with almost all browsers.

Comment: I know what you're saying about the JS... for stuff our users use we use it freely. however, for public-facing pages we're more conservative IF we can implement what we need reasonably nicely w/o JS.

Comment: I don't and couldn't judge your needs, that's why I suggested a non js solution first :)

Comment: I'll probably end up doing both, using jquery tabs in several places for our registered-user site. In fact that's what I'm working on now... although since I'm not a JS guy figuring out how to drop it into my rails app is making my head hurt (esp. theming). Anyway, GREAT tips, thanks!

Comment: JQuery UI has changed my life ;) Thanks!